# Creating an attachment for MailMessage

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

From my extbase 6.2 extension I want to send different e-mails.
In a controller class I wrote a mail function that looks like this:
(notice no `@param` for `$attachment` - see my question at the end)

```
/**
 * 
 * @param string $to
 * @param string $subject
 * @param string $email_prefix
 * @param string $msg
 * @param string $email_suffix
 */
public function mailAction($to, $subject, $email_prefix, $msg, $email_suffix, $attachment = null) {
    try {
        $from = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\MailUtility::getSystemFrom();
        $body = $email_prefix
                . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
                . $msg
                . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
                . $email_suffix;
        $htmlBody = nl2br($body);
        $toEmail = $to;
        $mail = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
        $mail->setFrom($from)
                ->setTo(array($toEmail))
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->setBody($htmlBody, 'text/html');
        $mail->addPart($body, 'text/plain');
        if ($attachment) {
            $mail->attach($attachment);
        }
        if (empty($toEmail) || strpos($toEmail, '@') === FALSE) {
            $this->addFlashMessage('Die Mail konnte nicht verschickt werden! Keine Email-Adresse des Empfängers', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::ERROR
            );
        } else {
            if ($mail->send()) {
                $this->addFlashMessage('Die Mail für wurde verschickt!', '');
            } else {
                $this->addFlashMessage('Die Mail konnte nicht verschickt werden!', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::ERROR
                );
            }
        }
        $this->redirect('list');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

In a function that calls the mail function I tried creating an attachment like this but it failed saying: `Fatal error: Class 'Swift_Attachment' not found in.../...Controller.php`

```
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::newInstance()
                ->setFilename('Termine.html')
                ->setContentType('text/html')
                ->setBody($emailView->render());
```

Then I call the mail function like this:

```
$this->redirect('mail', null, null, array(
            $to,
            $subject,
            $email_prefix,
            $msg,
            $email_suffix,
            $attachment));
```

My questions:

1. **How can I successfully create an object of type `Swift_Attachment` in a controller of my extbase extension (without creating a `MailMessage` object beforehand and creating the attachment inside of it)?**
2. **What should I put after `@param` as the type of my `$attachment` variable in my mail function for this to work?**

-- EDIT --

Ok, so apparently no one does that because it's not meant to be.
I now used Rene's approach combining it with Dimitri's scalable answer for multiple attachments. My @param is now `array` because I have to create the actual attachment after instantiating `MailMessage` - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my extension for 6.2.25 ist works without any including:

```
$email->attach(\Swift_Attachment::newInstance(
  $emailView->render(), 
  'Termine.html', 
  'text/html'
));
```

So you should check why your autoload of classes don't work. Have you tried to clear the cache complete?

To your second question: the correct param declaration should be:

```
@param \Swift_Mime_Attachment $attachment
```

But I wouldn't make an redirect, but an $this->forward. You don't need an redirection on client side for this. If this action is only called by an other action I also recommend to make it an protected function an call it directly from your action:

```
$this->sendMail($to, $subject, $email_prefix, $msg, $email_suffix, $attachment)
```

-- EDIT --

I recommend to use bypass the attachment information to the function to create the attachment object after the SwitftMailer was initialized:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param string $to
 * @param string $subject
 * @param string $email_prefix
 * @param string $msg
 * @param string $email_suffix
 * @param array  $attachment
 */
public function mailAction($to, $subject, $email_prefix, $msg, $email_suffix, $attachment = null) {
  ...
  if (is_array($attachment) && array_key_exist('content', $attachment) && array_key_exist('filename', $attachment) && array_key_exist('mime', $attachment)) {
    $mail->attach(\Swift_Attachment::newInstance($attachment['content'], $attachment['filename'], $attachment['mime']));
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think there's the problem like Jigal said in his answer - I don't have the `$email`object instantiated yet because I want to instantiate the attachment first. And according to his answer the `Swift_Attachment` class gets loaded when instantiating the `MailMessage` class. So I wonder how to instantiate it without the mail class, otherwise idk how I could test your @param type.
I find your forward and protected suggestion very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Damn, than I not read the answer correctly... Another way could be to bypass the content, filename and mimetype to the function to initialize it after the mail creation. I edited my ansewer.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage` there is a `require_once` for the swiftmailer classes; they don't seem to be autoloaded. Maybe you can pass the attachment as rendered HTML and create the `Swift_Attachment` object after instantiating the `MailMessage` object?
2. If the solution in 1. works it would be a simple string.

Comment: is there a way to create a `\Swift_Attachment` without having created `MailMessage` objects before?  If so should I use `ext_autoload.php` for that and what would I have to write in it? Otherwise I should probably make an array with the values for `->setFilename()`, `->setContentType()` and `->setBody()`. But not sure about the string type because in some cases I want to attach a .pdf file.

Comment: The mailMessage class has
`// Make sure Swift's auto-loader is registered ↵
require_once PATH_typo3 . 'contrib/swiftmailer/swift_required.php';`
in the file (just above the class declaration).
(In v7 this is better implemented and everything is autoloaded)

Comment: Alright something to look forward to when upgrading again :D

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by Jigal van Hemert you can only create the attachment objects after you create the MailMessage object because the class is not autoloaded. I would just pass the attachment as a filepath to your mail function and it should be handled there and not outside.

```
if ($attachment) {
    $email->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment));
}
```

In my opinion it makes more sense if you can pass multiple files instead of one, so the `$attachment` should be an `$attachments` array

```
        if(count($attachments)) {
            foreach ($attachments as $name => $file) {
                if(file_exists($file)) { 
                    if(trim($name) && !is_numeric($name)) {
                        $email->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file)->setFilename($name));
                    } else {
                        $email->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```